# I provided answer, edit and comments but the next day the question is deleted. Should I react on this?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509136/independence-of-complementary-events) is the question mentioned in the title. It bothers me that - without any explanation - the OP has deleted it. I can communicate this (especially the fact that I dislike it, and wonder about his motivation to delete) in a comment on some other question posed by the OP, but have my doubts about that. There is not much to win anyway, and I have never seen a comment like that. Is there a way to reach users directly? If not then would it be a good idea to create such a way?

Comment: Problem solved LOL (just upvoted)

Comment: This is one (of many) problems with that people don't vote enough. If your answer had been upvoted, the OP wouldn't have been able to delete the question.

Comment: To answer your last question, [private messages](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3129/10014) will probably never happen on this website. I think flagging for mod attention would be appropriate here.

Comment: [This chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete) might sometimes help. I seems that there have been [some request for undelete votes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=2165&q=undelete) in that room.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. You have been most kind and helpful. Gained some upvotes too :-).

Comment: Yes. Feel free to flag such occurrences. It's dishonest for users to ask and then delete immediately upon getting an answer.

Comment: @mixedmath I object to  "It's dishonest for users to ask and then delete immediately upon getting an answer." While usually it is not a good idea, there can be plenty of reasons why a user might delete that have nothing to do with a lack of honesty (a main one being  a lack of understanding how the site works.)

Comment: There are people who do not vote objectively. As an example, I got downvoted because I didn't provide full solution, on purpose,  for a homework problem.

At any rate, I don't visit this site to collect votes.

Mysterious comment deletions are quite irritating to be fair. You had gone through the trouble of reading, thinking and replying to the OP and as a "thank you" you get shown the middle finger and with no explanation to boot - that is, indeed, a sad attitude.

Comment: One reason OPs delete a question, is when the question is marked as a duplicate, but receives an answer. If the answer to this duplicate question provides no new insight over the answer to the other question, then deleting the question is totally appropriate in my opinion. I try my best not to write duplicate questions, but when I do it is best to delete it so that stackexchange doesn't get polluted.